# Using button on a page with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am scraping a page for some data, however I need to insert text into a text box, submit the form and scrape the result page. I looked at the page source, but I'm not sure how to activate the button or pass down the argument for it.

Website is http://archive.org/web/web.php
Trying to look at some historicals, and no idea what to use for this. Open to any solution

Comment: No idea, i updated the question. I am using Python for scraping

Comment: I am reading documentation on web and Python, nothing button wise so far. Hence i asked here

Comment: there are many ways to send http requests via python : use `requests` and you write up the parameters yourself or automate submission by something like `mechanize`

Comment: submitting text box with a button would be POST then? in requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should know that click on that button usually does a **POST** to some urls, passes the data in that form, here is:

```
<form id="wwmform" name="wwmform" method="get" action="http://web.archive.org/form-submit.jsp" onsubmit="document.location.href='http://web.archive.org/web/*/'+document.getElementById('wwmurl').value;return false;" style="display:inline;">
      <input id="wwmurl" type="text" name="url" size="50" value="http://">
      <button type="submit" name="type" value="urlquery" class="roundbox5">Take Me Back</button>
    </form>
```

you see the *action* attribute? That's where the data goes to.

So in python, you may need `urllib` and `urllib2` to encode the data and post it to the target url and then fetch the outcome.

ps: watch out the `onsubmit`

Comment: what do you mean by watch out?

Comment: @rodling it handles the submit action and redirect to another url other than which the `action` indicates, which is by default.

Comment: @rodling so just fetch that url, see the code in `onsubmit` to know how to construct the url(finally in python of course)

Comment: well identified that I have to use that form, i am just unclear on how to use that block. I have no problem with constructing what goes into it, just no idea how to submit that form. Kinda new to this

Comment: params = urllib.urlencode({'id':"wwmform", 'name': "wwmform", 'method': "get", 'action':"http://web.archive.org/form-submit.jsp", 'onsubmit':"document.location.href='http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ae?s=MSFT'.value",'style': "display:inline;"})

i also tried with POST as a method but i get the initial page rather than one it should send me to

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26212/discussion-between-topro-and-rodling)